# Dont read properly next line in batch

Tags: batch-file

When I am running my batch file to set environment some variables it shows the full path of `path_to_inpass`, but when it goes with `path_to_perl` and `path_to_system_dir` which includes `%path_to_inpass%`", it shows just ending what is after `%path_to_inpass%`.

But when I run the batch file again it have done it correctly.

```
@echo off

SETX path_to_inpass "C:\Program Files\InPass"
SETX path_to_perl "%path_to_inpass%\System\perl\bin"
SETX path_to_system_dir "%path_to_inpass%\System"
SETX path_to_system_temp_upgrade_dir "%temp%\inpass_upgrade"
```

Comment: The behavior is you have reported is expected. `SetX` writes the variables to the registry, therefore the variables will not be available until a new `cmd.exe` session is opened.

Comment: How i can right away read in that same cmd?

Comment: Use `Set` instead of or as well as `SetX` or possibly open a new `cmd` session for the rest of your script. Open a Command Prompt window and enter `set /?`, then repeat for `cmd /?`, this should output the usage information.

Answer (score 1):

The [`setx` command](https://ss64.com/nt/setx.html) writes the variables to the Windows Registry and makes them therefore available in the **next** Command Prompt (`cmd.exe`) instance.

To make variables also available in the *current* `cmd` instance, use a normal [`set` command](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) instead:

```cmd
@echo off
setx path_to_inpass "C:\Program Files\InPass"
set "path_to_inpass=C:\Program Files\InPass"
setx path_to_perl "%path_to_inpass%\System\perl\bin"
setx path_to_system_dir "%path_to_inpass%\System"
setx path_to_system_temp_upgrade_dir "%temp%\inpass_upgrade"
```